# Apache Thrift external event loop

Tags: c++, thrift, event-loop

In C++, how can I make an Apache Thrift server process external events? I'd like to write my own event loop and manually make Thrift process pending events without blocking.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
//...
TSimpleServer server(processor,
                       serverTransport,
                       transportFactory,
                       protocolFactory);

boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
t.async_wait(&onTimer);

while (!finished)
{
    server.poll();
    io.poll();
}
```

In the above while loop, I realize that there will be a lot of wasteful busy-waiting if there are no pending events. Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried [TNonBlockingServer](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp)?

Comment: "*Any suggestions on how to avoid wasetful polling?*" - Sure. Don't poll.

Comment: I've seen TNonBlockingServer, but I don't know how to make it poll, nor how to plug in I/O events of my own. If nobody answers, I'll dig into this some more and will attempt to answer my own question.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not so positive that this is a good idea. What is the purpose of `io.poll()`? Wouldn't a separate thread be the better choice? Could you add some background info? Maybe there is a much better way to do it. Discussing this particular stuff on the mailing list could help as well, as it is not the standard use case.

Comment: The server will be running on an embedded system that monitors sensors and performs serial communications with devices. I was planning on using Boost.Asio for timers and serial communications, and I need it to interoperate with Thrift's event loop.

I am purposely avoiding a multi-threaded design and would prefer to use an asynchronous concurrency model.

Comment: If you don't mind to do the communication part on your own, you can still use thrift to process the incoming data to it and get response data. You basically instantiate the processor and feed the data into it, via buffered or stream transports or the like.

Comment: I think I have to decide if want make my own a Protobuf+Boost.Asio solution, or hack Thrift to accommodate Boost.Asio. It seems that someone started working on a Thrift+Asio solution (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-579), but I have no idea if it's ready for prime time or not.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in way to make Apache Thrift interoperate with Boost.Asio or any other external event loop.

It is indeed possible to write your own Asio-based Thrift client/server. There is an ongoing Apache Thrift JIRA task (with experimental code) where they are working on such:

[THRIFT-579: Alternative ASIO based fully async client/server for C++](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-579)

They seem to need someone to finalize and maintain the alternative Asio-based client/server.

Here's a snippet from their [sample server program](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12419409/CppServer.cpp) which shows how the `TAsioServer` can be passed in a `boost::asio::io_service`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  boost::shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new protocol::TBinaryProtocolFactory());
  boost::shared_ptr<CalculatorAsyncHandler> handler(new CalculatorAsyncHandler(io_service));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new CalculatorAsyncProcessor(handler));

  boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::async::TAsioServer> server(
                                   new apache::thrift::async::TAsioServer(
                                                      io_service,
                                                      9090,
                                                      protocolFactory,
                                                      protocolFactory,
                                                      processor));

  server->start(); // Nonblocking
  io_service.run(); // Blocking

  return 0;
}
```

Using their `TAsioServer`, one should be able to make, for example, a `boost::asio::serial_port` and `boost::asio::deadline_timer` use the same `boost::asio::io_service`.

Comment: Ok. I still recommend to throw a post into the mailing lists. At least you should be able to find one of the C++ guys to discuss that matter in more detail. Maybe THRIFT-579 gets some traction? Regarding protobuf: You may use Thrift serialization without RPC, that's perfectly fine. No need to switch bases ;-)

Comment: I'm not yet committed to either Protobuf or Thrift, the choice is still open. If it weren't for the fact that THRIFT-579 needs to patch the trunk (it's not purely an add-on), I would just use THRIFT-579 as a starting point for my own Thrift customization. But I'm not comfortable working with a patched-up Thrift. I might consider volunteering to help completion of THRIFT-579, but the time investment in fully understanding how Thrift works might outweigh the time it would take me to roll my own Asio-based RPC on top of Protobuf.